# Trying to find a way to convert two lists into a map where one list acts as the key and the other as the value

Tags: list, dart, maps

Trying to find a way to convert two lists into a map where one list acts as the key and the other as the value. I'm new to dart and trying to exercise some of the functions I learned but can't seem to find an effective way to do so.

I tried to convert 1 list to a map and then access the keys in a for loop and replace them with the values from the other list, but apparently that's not possible?

Any suggestions will be appreciated :)
Thanks

EDIT: ok I feel dumb.

This is the solution for anyone wondering.

final theMap = Map.fromIterables(months, salesFigures);

Comment: If you found the solution yourself, it is best to post it as an answer to your own question. That make it easier to see for others.